# Saving gridview updated data to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, devexpress

I can save data in my gridView but I am unable to do so to my datasource.
Could there a missing line of code or is there something that I am missing?

Here's my code:

```
public Marksheet(object val1)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        string connectionString = null;
        SqlConnection conn; 
        connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=jms";
        SqlDataAdapter sda6 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM grades WHERE class_code='" + val1 + "'", connectionString);
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        DataTable dt5 = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda6.Fill(dt5);
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt5;
}

private void gridControl1_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick(object sender, NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
         if (e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.EndEdit)
         {
             if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to commit changes to the current record?", "Confirm commit",

                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) != DialogResult.No)
             {
                 gridView1.CloseEditor();
                 gridView1.UpdateCurrentRow();
             }   
         }
}

private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //?? Could there be something I'm missing here? if yes, what could it be?
}
```

Comment: you mean saving to sql server?

Comment: yes saving to sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make any changes to the grid control, the changes are reflected in the datasource, that is in your case a `DataTable`. If you think logically, it seems correct as the Grid Control is bound to the `DataTable` and is not aware about how the `DataTable` gets populated.

Now you can see that the `DataTable` is populated using `DataAdapter`. You need to call the `DataAdapter.Update(dataTable)` method to push the changes to database.

As described here  - [Posting Data to a Connected Database](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1082)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is already suggested by @Aseem that you need to implement ADO.net binding to commit changes back to the back-end using the *`DataAdapter`*. If you can implement this way then check below tutorial:

[Tutorial: ADO.NET Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114682)

> When binding to a database using ADO.NET, you bind a control to a
>   DataTable containing data from the database. When you change data via
>   the Grid Control (adding, deleting or modifying records), the changes
>   are accumulated in the DataTable. They are not automatically posted to
>   the underlying database. Therefore, you need to manually call a
>   specific method to post the changes.

If you are using custom data table and not willing to implement such binging then you have to handle [GridView.RowUpdated Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_RowUpdatedtopic) and then you can post back then changes that you made in current updated row.

Refer this: [Xtragrid Row Updated Event](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q327946)

Example:

```
Private Sub gridView1_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowObjectEventArgs) Handles gridView1.RowUpdated
    Dim val As Object
    Dim row As DataRowView = CType(e.Row, DataRowView)
    val = row(0)
End Sub
```

Hope this help..